# C-style macros in R

Tags: r, function, macros

In C, a macro is like a function, but before compilation, any instance of the macro call is replaced by the text of the macro.

My use-case is this:

```
floor_dec <- function(x, sigDig=1) {
  if (x == 0) {return(x)} 
  if (is.infinite(x)) {return(x)}
  if (sigDig <= 0) {stop("Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.")}
  sigDig = round(sigDig)
  mostSig = ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
  floor(x*10^(sigDig-mostSig))*10^-(sigDig-mostSig)
}
ceil_dec <- function(x, sigDig=1) {
  if (x == 0) {return(x)} # This feels familiar
  if (is.infinite(x)) {return(x)} # So does this...
  if (sigDig <= 0) {stop("Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.")} # Wait a minute
  sigDig = round(sigDig)
  mostSig = ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
  ceiling(x*10^(sigDig-mostSig))*10^-(sigDig-mostSig)
}
```

The parameter checking section of these two functions is the exact same, so I'd like to write it once and then just refer to it. The issue is that I can't just plop the code into another function. An inner function would need to use a sentinel variable to notify the outer function to return early, and another variable to store the value that I'm returning.

My first approach was a `gtools::defmacro`, but that didn't seem to do what I wanted and seemed to act just like any other function. Next I tried to work with substitutations like this:

```
.check_dec_parameters <- substitute({
  if (x == 0) {return(x)}
  if (is.infinite(x)) {return(x)}
  if (sigDig <= 0) {stop("Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.")}
})

ceil_dec <- function(x, sigDig=1) {
  eval(.check_dec_parameters)
  sigDig = round(sigDig)
  mostSig = ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
  ceiling(x*10^(sigDig-mostSig))*10^-(sigDig-mostSig)
}
```

But the returns in `.check_dec_parameters` don't appear to return from the outer function. The `stop()` works correctly, so halfway there, I guess. Can anyone let me know how to get to the end, possibly with an explanation? I'm reading through http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html to see where I may be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be using a [function operator](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-operators.html) to add your parameter check:

```r
# define function operator
add_parameter_check <- function(fn) {
  force(fn)
  function(x, sigDig = 1, ...) {   # `...` to accommodate other arguments to `fn`
    if (x == 0) {return(x)} 
    if (is.infinite(x)) {return(x)}
    if (sigDig <= 0) {stop("Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.")}
    fn(x = x, sigDig = sigDig, ...)
  }
}

# define function without parameter checks
floor_dec <- function(x, sigDig = 1) {
  sigDig = round(sigDig)
  mostSig = ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
  floor(x * 10^(sigDig - mostSig)) * 10^-(sigDig - mostSig)
}
# then add parameter checks
floor_dec <- add_parameter_check(floor_dec)

# likewise for ceil_dec()
ceil_dec <- function(x, sigDig = 1) {
  sigDig = round(sigDig)
  mostSig = ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
  ceiling(x * 10^(sigDig - mostSig)) * 10^-(sigDig - mostSig)
}
ceil_dec <- add_parameter_check(ceil_dec)
```

Results:

```r
floor_dec(12)
# 10
floor_dec(Inf)
# Inf
floor_dec(12, sigDig = -1)
# Error in floor_dec(12, sigDig = -1) : 
#   Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.

ceil_dec(12)
# 20
ceil_dec(Inf)
# Inf
ceil_dec(12, sigDig = -1)
# Error in floor_dec(12, sigDig = -1) : 
#   Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, though my implementation will also resemble Mikael's answer. I think the decorator pattern here can be changed to a `.` hidden factory function where I give it the functions namesake operator and it spits out the function I needed.

Answer (score 3):

R allows for computing on the language, but it's different than a macro text replacement. You can't "return" from an `eval` without a function context. Another strategy would be to create wrappers. For example you can do

```
wrap_dec <- function(expr) {
  function(x, sigDig=1) {
    if (x == 0) {return(x)} # This feels familiar
    if (is.infinite(x)) {return(x)} # So does this...
    if (sigDig <= 0) {stop("Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.")} # Wait a minute
    sigDig = round(sigDig)
    mostSig = ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
    eval(expr)    
  }
}

floor_dec <- wrap_dec(quote(floor(x*10^(sigDig-mostSig))*10^-(sigDig-mostSig)))
ceil_dec <- wrap_dec(quote(ceiling(x*10^(sigDig-mostSig))*10^-(sigDig-mostSig)))

floor_dec(1.4, 1)
# [1] 1
ceil_dec(1.2, -1)
# Error in ceil_dec(1.2, -1) : Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.
ceil_dec(0, -1)
# [1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions that return functions have the caveat that the called and returned functions will have different evaluation environments unless you arrange otherwise with a suitable call to `environment<-`.

To avoid those types of gotchas, just define a template function containing a "macro" and `substitute` into the body:

```r
floor_dec <- ceil_dec <- function(x, sigDig = 1) {
    if (x == 0) {return(x)} 
    if (is.infinite(x)) {return(x)}
    if (sigDig <= 0) {stop("Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.")}
    sigDig <- round(sigDig)
    mostSig <- ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
    .__FUNC__.(x*10^(sigDig-mostSig))*10^-(sigDig-mostSig)
}

body(floor_dec) <- do.call(substitute, list(body(floor_dec), list(.__FUNC__. = quote(floor))))
body( ceil_dec) <- do.call(substitute, list(body( ceil_dec), list(.__FUNC__. = quote( ceil))))
```

Another option is `bquote`, which does the same thing under the hood:

```r
fnm <- c("floor_dec", "ceil_dec")
sym <- expression(floor, ceiling)
for (i in 1:2)
    assign(fnm[i], 
           removeSource(eval(bquote(function(x, sigDig = 1) {
               if (x == 0) {return(x)} 
               if (is.infinite(x)) {return(x)}
               if (sigDig <= 0) {stop("Error: sigDig must be a positive integer.")}
               sigDig <- round(sigDig)
               mostSig <- ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
               .(sym[[i]])(x*10^(sigDig-mostSig))*10^-(sigDig-mostSig)
           }))))
```

Both of these approaches should feel (at least conceptually) closer to using C preprocessor macros, being based on substitution of symbols into code fragments.